# Calls are getting routed to the driver, when application uses poll() and not with epoll() in linux

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, epoll

Application calls are getting routed to the driver poll method when using `poll()` and not with `epoll()`. Can any one have an idea why this is happening ? below is my application code with epoll. And another observation is, `epoll_ctl()` call is getting routed to the driver but not `epoll_wait()`.

```
struct epoll_event ev, events[MAX_EPOLL_EVENTS];
int epfd, nfds;
epfd = epoll_create(MAX_EPOLL_EVENTS);
ev.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET;
ev.data.fd = fd; /* fd is an open file descriptor */
if (epoll_ctl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, fd, &ev) == -1) {
    printf("epoll_ctl failed\n");
}

nfds = epoll_wait(epfd, &events, MAX_EPOLL_EVENTS, 10000);
```

Comment: Isn't that how it's supposed to work?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I'm not sure how it suppose to work. Can you explain a bit if you know

Comment: Is there a difference if you don't use EPOLLET ? EPOLLET is very different from how poll() behaves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation for poll and epoll are different.

Before all, we know the `poll` of driver always calls `poll_wait()`. This is the most important difference for these 2 system calls.

#### poll/select

The `poll` of driver is called every time when poll/select is called from userspace. It add current process to the wait queue and add the wait queue to `poll_table`.

1. Userspace polled 2 different file descriptors
2. kernel called every file descriptors' `poll` driver.
3. The `poll` drivers called `poll_wait`. It added current process in the `poll_table`
4. Assume that they were not ready either. So there were 2 wait queues in the `poll table`.
5. When 1 of the file descriptor was ready, it waked the process up.
6. The waked process then called every file descriptors' `poll` driver again to check which file descriptor was ready.
7. At last, it returned to userspace.

#### epoll

The `poll` of driver is only called by `epoll_ctl`.

1. Userspace called `epoll_ctl` to setup 2 different file descriptors
2. kernel called every file descriptors' `poll` driver.
3. The `poll` drivers called `poll_wait`. But this time `poll_wait` is different from poll/select. It not only add current process in the `poll_table` but also changed the call back function to `ep_poll_callback` when the process was waked.
4. Assume that they were not ready either. So now there were 2 wait queues in the `poll table`.
5. When 1 of the file descriptor was ready, it waked the process up.
6. So the `ep_poll_callback` is called. It add the corresponding file descriptor to the ready queue of `epoll`
7. `epoll_wait` checked the ready queue periodically and found the ready one.
8. At last, it returned to userspace.